# MacVim colour scheme shortcuts

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there a (default) keyboard shortcut for MacVim to quickly change between the various provided colour schemes?

I have done a couple of google searches and obviously I know I can change them from the Edit menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colorscheme switcher plug-in for the Vim text editor makes it easy to quickly switch between [colorschemes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:colorscheme). It defines commands and mappings to switch to the next and previous color schemes.

[Color scheme switcher for Vim](https://github.com/xolox/vim-colorscheme-switcher)

Comment: Is there a default keyboard shortcut without having to install a plug in?

Comment: No, there is no default keyboard shortcut for theme switching.